# when configuring persistent system journals, after restarting systemd-journald /var/log/journal folder didn't create

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-journald

When configuring persistent system journals, after restarting systemd-journald /var/log/journal folder didn't create.

I did following steps:

1. become root
2. edited and saved `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` with the changes

```
    [Journal] 
    Storage=persistent
```

3. restarted systemd-journald service

and no folder created with the name /var/log/journal.

What can I do here or can I copy the folder in /run/log/journal
to the destination where it must be?

Comment: What does `systemctl status systemd-journald` say?

Comment: Rather than setting `Storage=persistent`, it is sufficient to leave it at `Storage=auto` and `mkdir /var/log/journal`. The journal will then be copied to this directory in a few seconds.

Comment: ....                                                                                                                          
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-journald.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2021-07-04 03:45:39 +04; 9h ago                             .........

Comment: yes, it worked as u said,  I kept Storage=auto as it is, and then mkdir.. thus it worked fine

Answer (score 2):

When switching from **volatile** to **persistent**, I had to issue `journalctl --flush` to make journald switch over to the new logging location.